# Can find a bug in simple Place a bet function

Tags: c#, .net

Here`s the code:

```
private static int[] PlaceBet()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Placed numbers: ");
        foreach (int num in numbers)
        {
            if (num > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(num + ", ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n Choose a number from 1 to 49");
        Console.Write("{0}/6: ", i + 1);
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int number) && number >= 1 && number <= 49 && Array.IndexOf(numbers, number) == -1)
        {
            numbers[i] = number;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, it's an invalid number");
            i--;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    return numbers;
}
```

I dont understand why all the time the number is 0 and instantly i get an error message "Unfortunately, it's an invalid number".
The logic is pretty obvius, i ask for number, check if it is between 0-49, if yes, i add it to an array and then ask again;

https://codeshare.io/MNrb03

Answer (score 1):

You check for "number >= 1", so 0 is not valid. Apart from that you always need to press enter after you entered an invalid number, maybe consider to remove the "Console.ReadKey()" in the else block.

Comment: The `Console.ReadKey()` is the cause of the error. After placing an incorrect number and typing a correct number this correct number is beeing read by ReadKey().

Comment: @Heslacher - seems like your comment should be an answer, but then again what you are saying seems incorrect as the Console.ReadKey prevents Console.Clear from immediately clearing the error msg and the user has to „accept“ the error before code moves on. so the error message could be extended with "Unfortunately, it's an invalid number. **Press any key to continue**"

Comment: but the 0 is invalid; i wonder why when i run the programm, i get the error messagne even though i didnt even type anythig

Comment: how do i fix it? https://codeshare.io/MNrb03

Comment: you solution doesnt work :<

Comment: @RandRandom I just thought as duketo already wrote about the `Console.ReadKey()` that I only place a comment, but now I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your method works fine if any number you input is in the specific range between 1 and 49. Your problems starts if you once enter a incorrect value, because of the "viewing part" of your method. You want and maybe need to show that the entered value is incorrect hence you placed a `Console.ReadKey()` after displaying the errormessage. Now a user would just enter the next number hitting return, which means the next number is read by `Console.ReadKey()` and the `return` would be read by `Console.ReadLine()` which results in an empty string which shows you again the errormessage.
You should either change your errormessage to `Unfortunately, it's an invalid number. Press any key to continue` or change the place where you output the other messages.

As I come form [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I just couldn't help it to beautify the code a little bit ;-)

```
private static int[] PlaceBet()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[6];
    OutputSuccess(numbers);
    Console.Write("0/6: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(input, out int number) && number >= 1 && number <= 49 && Array.IndexOf(numbers, number) == -1)
        {
            numbers[i] = number;
            OutputSuccess(numbers);
            Console.Write("{0}/6: ", i + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            OutputError(number);
            i--;
        }
    }
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    return numbers;
}
private static void OutputSuccess(int[] numbers)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write($"Placed numbers: {string.Join(",", numbers.Where(i => i != 0))}");
    Console.WriteLine("\n Choose a number from 1 to 49");
}
private static void OutputError(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Unfortunately the number {number} is either already choosen or not in the expected range.");
    Console.WriteLine("\n Choose a number from 1 to 49");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be simply missing the output for the last number 6 out of 6, since your output is inside the loop and you are prematurely exiting on the last number.

So I extended your for loop with `+ 1` and added a break condition after your output logic `if (i + 1 == 7) break;`

See it in action here
[sharplab.io Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Here a demo with a random generator of numbers 1 to 9, which will more likely run into your invalid number routine
[sharlab.io Demo 1 to 9](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Notice I have removed `Console.Clear/Console.ReadLine/Console.ReadKey` and the input of numbers is a random number.